# Scala: case classes converted to object

Tags: scala, akka

I have two case classes like these -

```
case class GetList()
case class Add(num: Int)
```

I have an actor whose receive method looks like this -

```
override def receive() = {
  case a: Add => // do something
  case g: GetList => // do something
  case x: Any => // something
}
```

I am calling the actor as -

```
ref ! Add(1)
ref ! GetList
```

For the Add(1) message, I am getting a hit on a: Add in receive. But for the GetList message it's going to x: Any.
On closer inspection I found the instance I am getting is of type GetList$ which usually denotes an "object".

Who is doing this conversion and why? What is the rationale behind such a weird behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your better off making `GetList` a `case object` instead so your new code would look like `case object GetList` and this way you don't have to worry about empty parenthesis. The other thing to note is that empty case classes have been deprecated as well.

Comment: Thanks. In addition I had to change my receive matcher also to look like `case GetList` instead of `case g: GetList`

Answer (score 3):

As GetList is case class without parameters. You have to call it as `GetList()` not `GetList`

```
ref ! GetList()
```

So change `ref ! GetList` to `ref ! GetList()`

`GetList` is the corresponding companion object of the case class `GetList`. If you want the instance of the case class you have to do `GetList()`

> Beware of the case classes with empty constructors.

Instead make case object

```
case object GetList
```

From scala version 2.11.1 empty case classes are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conversion, it's just how case classes work: when you write `case class GetList()`, it's equivalent to

```
class GetList() { ... }
object GetList { ... }
```

(with some methods defined automatically inside `{ ... }`).

So `ref ! GetList` sends the *value* `GetList`, which isn't an instance of the *class* `GetList`. And `case g: GetList` succeeds when it gets an instance of the class.